# Avoid enclosing shortcodes in <p> in ckeditor 4

Tags: ckeditor

Is there any solution to use shortcodes [somethig] in ckeditor and not having them enclosed in paragraphs ?

When i use only one per line it turns to something like

```
<p>[shortcode]</p>
... rest of the html code
[p][/shortcode]</p>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution to your question?

Comment: Unfortunately i didn’t. Im using php to process the result and remove extra <p